# How to bind the same event for each element in component without adding one by one manually?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a lot of elements in my component, because it's a SVG like:

```
export default mySVG = ({ onPress }) => (
    <Svg>
        <Circle ref='circle1' r="40" />
        <Circle ref='circle2' r="30" />
        <Circle ref='circle3' r="34" />
        <Circle ref='circle4' r="35" />
        <Circle ref='circle5' r="100" />
        <Circle ref='circle6' />
        <Rect />
        <Path ref='path1' />
        <Circle ref='circle7' />
        <Circle ref='circle8' />
        <Circle ref='circle9' />
        <Rect />
        <Path ref='path2' />
    </Svg>
)
```

What I wanna do is bind onPress event to each one of those Circle and Path (except Rect).

So I can't bind event to `<Svg>` element and this code is just an example, it could much more bigger, so it could be hard to add `onPress={onPress}` (or any other repeat code) one by one.

Is there any way to bind the same event to each those automatically?

---

Edit 1:
I'm needing to handle some complex SVG, that's the reason that I'm avoiding to pass props to those components one by one, it could be thousand components.

Once component's clicked, it should pass it's `ref` as parameter.

I tried to set event by `setNativeProps` in `componentDidMount` like:

```
componentDidMount() {
    for(let key in this.refs) {
        this.refs[ key ].setNativeProps({
            onPress: this.props.onPress.bind(this, key)
        });
    }
}
```

But it seems not working to set event, only to properties like `fill`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can do something like that:

```
const MyCircle = ({ onPress }) => {
    return <MyCircle onPress={onPress} />
};

const MyPath = ({ onPress }) => {
    return <MyPath onPress={onPress} />
};

export default mySVG = (props) => (
    <Svg>
        <MyCircle ref='circle1' {...props} />
        <MyCircle ref='circle2' {...props} />
        <MyCircle ref='circle3' {...props} />
        <MyCircle ref='circle4' {...props} />
        <MyCircle ref='circle5' {...props} />
        <MyCircle ref='circle6' {...props} />
        <Rect {...props} />
        <MyPath ref='path1' {...props} />
        <MyCircle ref='circle7' {...props} />
        <MyCircle ref='circle8' {...props} />
        <MyCircle ref='circle9' {...props} />
        <Rect {...props} />
        <MyPath ref='path2' {...props} />
    </Svg>
)
```

EDIT:

But what about your structure of mySVG component? Is it fixed like that? Then maybe it would be easier if you create a list like

```
const svgElements = ['Circle', 'Circle', 'Circle', 'Circle', 'Circle', 'Circle', 'Rect', 'Path', 'Circle', etc...]
```

and map over it with function like:

```
export default ({onPress}) => {
    const svgElements = ['Circle', 'Circle', 'Circle', 'Circle', 'Circle', 'Circle', 'Rect', 'Path', 'Circle'];
    const svgContent = svgElements.map((svgElement, i) => {
        switch(svgElement) {
            case 'Circle':
                return <Circle ref={`circle${i}`} onPress={onPress} />;
            case 'Rect':
                return <Rect ref={`rect${i}`} />;
            case 'Path':
                return <Path ref={`path${i}`} onPress={onPress} />;
        }
    });
    return (
        <Svg>
            {svgContent}
        </Svg>
    )
}
```

Comment: Sorry, maybe I was not clear enough, but what I'm avoiding to do is repeat the same code to each component.

Comment: I made an edit, but not sure if it's what you were looking for.

Comment: Sorry for my bad sample code, but all of them have different properties.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, what you can do is to create a custom component that does the `onPress` event and then you can use that components rather than `Circle` and `Path` component directly. You can also override the `onPress` event if you want to this way.

```
export default class CustomCircle extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  _onPress() {
    console.log('this is onPress');
    if (this.props.onPress) {
      this.props.onPress();
    }
  }

  render() {
    return <Circle { ...this.props } onPress={ this._onPress } />
  }
}
```

---

```
export default class CustomPath extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  _onPress() {
    console.log('this is onPress');
    if (this.props.onPress) {
      this.props.onPress();
    }
  }

  render() {
    return <Path { ...this.props } onPress={ this._onPress } />
  }
}
```

---

```
export default mySVG = ({ onPress }) => (
    <Svg>
        <CustomCircle ref='circle1' onPress={onPress} />
        <CustomCircle ref='circle2' />
        <CustomCircle ref='circle3' />
        <CustomCircle ref='circle4' />
        <CustomCircle ref='circle5' />
        <CustomCircle ref='circle6' />
        <Rect />
        <CustomPath ref='path1' />
        <CustomCircle ref='circle7' />
        <CustomCircle ref='circle8' />
        <CustomCircle ref='circle9' />
        <Rect />
        <CustomPath ref='path2' />
    </Svg>
)
```

Comment: This is a different way of solution that I was looking for, but I think it should works very well to my case! Thank you so much!

Comment: Oh, maybe I'm wrong, this probably not gonna be works for me, I'm looking for something able to set event to each component like `jQuery`  `$( "[ref]" ).click( this.props.onPress );`. I know this is looks very bad, it's probably a wrong way to use React, otherwise, I'll need to pass `onPress` to all of them and I'm pretending to approach some more complex SVG.

Comment: I'm not sure but if you want to run a click function with jQuery why don't you just run onPress directly. Isn't it the same thing? Maybe you should extend your question with a better example and give a little bit more detail for a better answer.

Comment: I updated my question, sorry for unclear explanation. I'm not sure that I understood what you mean, but I can't run `onPress` directly in `componentDidMount` because it's not the moment, I only wanna add some event listener to those components dynamically, and fire it when I click on.